# Can't draw in opengl in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glut

I am trying to figure out how to make `opengl` work in `Windows 8.1` using `Visual Studio 2012`.

My program compiles and runs, but nothing happens in the windows which is created, I can't even change background color or see the mouse.

My program looks as follows:

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include "simpleViewer.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
simpleViewer Viewer;
Viewer.initOpenGL(argc, argv);
Viewer.run();
}
```

simpleViewer.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _SIMPLEVIEWER_H_
#define _SIMPLEVIEWER_H_
#include "GL\GL\glut.h"
#include <iostream>
enum DisplayModes {
DISPLAY_MODE_OVERLAY,
DISPLAY_MODE_DEPTH,
DISPLAY_MODE_IMAGE
};


class simpleViewer 
{
public:
simpleViewer(void);
~simpleViewer(void);
virtual void run();
virtual void initOpenGL(int argc, char **argv);
virtual void initOpenGLHooks();
virtual void display();
virtual void displayPostDraw(){};
DisplayModes m_eViewState;
private:
static simpleViewer* ms_self;
static void glutIdle();
static void glutDisplay();

};
#endif
```

and simpleViewer.cpp

```
#include "simpleViewer.h"

#define GL_WIN_SIZE_X   1280
#define GL_WIN_SIZE_Y   1024

// Undeprecate CRT functions
#ifndef _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE 
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE 1
#endif

simpleViewer* simpleViewer::ms_self;
simpleViewer::simpleViewer(void)
{
ms_self = this;
}


simpleViewer::~simpleViewer(void)
{
}

void simpleViewer::initOpenGL(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowSize(GL_WIN_SIZE_X, GL_WIN_SIZE_Y);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutCreateWindow ("Test");
//  glutFullScreen();
glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
initOpenGLHooks();
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glClearColor(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
}
void simpleViewer::initOpenGLHooks()
{
glutDisplayFunc(glutDisplay);
glutIdleFunc(glutIdle);
}
void simpleViewer::run(){
glutMainLoop();
}

void simpleViewer::display(){
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3f(1.0,0,0);
glVertex3f(0.1,0,0);
glVertex3f(0,0,0);
glVertex3f(0,0,0.1);
glEnd();
glFlush();

}
void simpleViewer::glutIdle(){
glutPostRedisplay();
}
void simpleViewer::glutDisplay(){
        simpleViewer::ms_self->display();
}
```

I have checked so that it really goes into display(), but nothing happens. The background is totally white even if it should be red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've requested double-buffering via `GLUT_DOUBLE`.

Use `glutSwapBuffers()` instead of `glFlush()` at the end of `simpleViewer::display()`.

`glClearColor()` only latches some state.  [`glClear()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClear.xml) actually does the clear.  Add a `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` at the top of `simpleViewer::display()`.

That triangle is wonky for the default projection/modelview matrices.  Try this instead:

```
glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
glVertex2i( 0, 0 );
glVertex2i( 1, 0 );
glVertex2i( 1, 1 );
glEnd();
```

You'll probably want to change the triangle color too.  Red on red is pretty hard to see :)

Comment: Ok, now the background is black instead, and no triangle yet and the mouse disappears when I move it over the window.

Comment: @Erik: The mouse thing is probably due to your `glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE)` call.